# how to plot data using matplotlib using groubby

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

How to plot grouped data using **groupby** until now i am able to display the data using group by but when i try to plot the result its not display identical to the groupby result.

## display result

```
df.groupby("event_type").aggregate('sum').to_dict()

{'number_person': {'meeting': 130,   'music concert': 99929,   'go out ': 1542,   'playing football': 53256,   'staying at home': 17312}}
```

## plot

```
df.groupby('event_type')['number_person'].nunique().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]

as you see the result of **plotting** does not match the result of **dictionary**

Comment: `df.groupby("event_type").aggregate('sum').plot.bar()`?

Comment: this was the answer thanks make it as answer to accept it.

and one question how to make the size of the figure bigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df.groupby("event_type").aggregate('sum').plot.bar(figsize=(10,6))
```

Or you can create an axis instance and plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
df.groupby("event_type").aggregate('sum').plot.bar(ax=ax)
```

Comment: what is the difference between the 2 answers ?

Comment: Not much different, the second gives you access to the `fig` instance if needed.

Comment: ok thank you for you help  sorry for the question can i use  groupby multiple column ?

Comment: Certainly, `df.groupby(['col1','col2'])`.

Comment: i tried this it display the below error:
`df.groupby("event_type","event_location").aggregate('sum').plot.bar(figsize=(10,6))`
`ValueError: No axis named event_location for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`